# How to set up two way binding between two variables in the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `currentDistrict` to display on the page. 
Initialized into an empty string:

```
$scope.currentDistrict = '';
```

and later is populated with a WebAPI call:

```
...
    $scope.currentDistrict = data.currentDistrict;
...
```

The retrieved district info is displayed in a diretive:

```
<district-selector current="currentDistrict"></district-selector>
```

Also, there is a form in the page, using a json object:

```
$scope.address = {
    'district': $scope.currentDistrict,
    'name': '',
    'street': '',
    'city': '',
    'state': '',
    'zip': '',
    'comments': ''
};
```

The form is using this `address` object:

I was hoping the `$scope.address.district` value will change along with `currentDistrict`. Say, if I change the current district, not only the `<district-selector>` will change, but the readonly textbox in the form should change also.

But it never does.

So the question is: how to change `$scope.address.district` when there is a change in `$scope.currentDistrict`?

If         `'district': $scope.currentDistrict,` won't set up the binding, what is the correct way to listen to the change of one variable and apply to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is perfect for `$watch` function:

```
$scope.$watch('currentDistrict', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.address.district = newVal;
});
```

By having this watch inside the controller, whenever the value of `currentDistrict` changes, it will be reflected in `address.district`.

Comment: Thanks. First time heard of `$watch`. It just works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use updateOn from [ngModelsOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

> Using ngModelOptions you can specify a custom list of events that will
>   trigger a model update....

**Simple Sample from AngularJS docs**

```
<input type="text" name="userName"
           ng-model="user.name"
           ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
           ng-keyup="cancel($event)" /><br />
```

In your case, when update/change currentDistrict then change the address.district